# Twitter login in browser when no app available

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter, twitter-oauth

I'm building a sample to authenticate with twitter, i went throw the documentation here :http://docs.fabric.io/ios/twitter/authentication.html

After implementing the login button it only access the accounts in the phone,if there is no account it just doesn't go to the browser and login instead. as Facebook or Google+.

This is what i have in `viewDidLoad` :

```
TWTRLogInButton* logInButton = [TWTRLogInButton buttonWithLogInCompletion:^(TWTRSession* session, NSError* error) {
    if (session) {
        self.userName.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[session userName]];
        self.UserID.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[session userID]];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
}];
logInButton.center = CGPointMake(190.0, 250.0);
[self.view addSubview:logInButton];


[[Twitter sharedInstance] logInWithCompletion:^(TWTRSession *session, NSError *error) {
    if (session) {
        self.userName.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[session userName]];
        self.UserID.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[session userID]];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
}];
```

And in `AppDelegate` :

```
[[Twitter sharedInstance] startWithConsumerKey:@"something" consumerSecret:@"another thing"];
[Fabric with:@[[Twitter sharedInstance]]];
```

How is it possible to allow signing-in using the browser ?

Comment: had you used twitter in your phone??

Comment: i can register it under Settings > Twitter, without an app, but if no app exist it should login throw browser

Comment: yes...check there if there is any apps under `allow access to Twitter accounts`.....just remove it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've added a `Callback URL` in Twitter application management under Settings Tab and then it works without deleting anything.

Comment: I have the same problem. What should be the callback URL? I am using Swift though

Comment: @VinodSobale Dear I've used a link for my company website : http://*******.com  that's it ! Let me know if it works !

Comment: It sure did. The only requirement is that is must not be empty

Comment: @AaoIi Thanks!! This is helpful